# docker push causes http error 413: client intended to send too large body

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have a minikube K8S cluster running on a hyperv vm.
The cluster has an nginx ingress controller to expose services to outside of the cluster.
Outside of the cluster requests are exposed to the internet through an nginx that runs on the host machine.

Inside the cluster I also have a kube-registry with kube-registry-proxy running to store my docker images.

There however is an issue when I try to push larger images (about 32mb). In this case I get a 413 with the following error in my host nginx logfile (redacted for privacy reasons):

```
<redactedIP> - - [<redactedLocalDateTime>] "PATCH /v2/<redactedImageName>/blobs/uploads/<redactedUuid>?_state=<redactedState>%3D HTTP/1.1" 413 183 "-" "docker/19.03.12 go/go1.13.10 git-commit/48a66213fe kernel/4.19.114 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.12 \x5C(windows\x5C))"
```

When looking in my ingress-nginx-controller logs in my k8s cluster, I see the following message:

```
[error] 371#371: *1004283 client intended to send too large body: 9930410 bytes, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "PATCH /v2/<redactedImageName>/blobs/uploads/<redactedUuid> HTTP/1.1", host: ".<redactedHost>"
```

And looking at my kube-registry logs, I don't see the PATCH request at all.
This suggests to me that the issue lies with the ingress-nginx-controller in my cluster.

I have looked into the issue and found some clues, regarding setting the `client_max_body_size` and `client_body_buffer_size`, either with the nginx configmap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  body-size: "1024m"
  proxy-body-size: "1024m"
  client-max-body-size: "1024m"
  client-body-buffer-size: "1024m"
```

This is set in the deployment of the ingress-nginx-controller using the `--configmap` argument

I also tried to set it using annotations on the kube-registry ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kube-registry-ingress
  name: kube-registry-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "1024m"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "1024m"
    ...
```

I also made sure that `client_max_body_size` and `client_body_buffer_size` were set in the host nginx config.

I verified that the nginx config from the ingress-nginx-controller was set:

```
http {                       
        client_body_buffer_size         1024m;           
   
        ...

        ## start server <redactedDomain>
        server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                server_name <redactedDomain> ;                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                listen 80  ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                listen 443  ssl http2 ;                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                set $proxy_upstream_name "-";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                               
                ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                        certificate.call()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                }                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                               
                        set $namespace      "kube-system";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                        set $ingress_name   "kube-registry-ingress";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                        set $service_name   "kube-registry-proxy";                                                                             
                        set $service_port   "80";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                        set $location_path  "/";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                               
                        rewrite_by_lua_block {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                lua_ingress.rewrite({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                        force_ssl_redirect = false,                                                                            
                                        ssl_redirect = true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                        force_no_ssl_redirect = false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                        use_port_in_redirects = false,                                                                         
                                })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                balancer.rewrite()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                plugins.run()                                                                                                  
                        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        # be careful with `access_by_lua_block` and `satisfy any` directives as satisfy any                                    
                        # will always succeed when there's `access_by_lua_block` that does not have any lua code doing `ngx.exit(ngx.DECLINED)`                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                        # other authentication method such as basic auth or external auth useless - all requests will be allowed.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        #access_by_lua_block {                                                                                                 
                        #}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        header_filter_by_lua_block {                                                                                           
                                lua_ingress.header()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                plugins.run()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                        }                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        body_filter_by_lua_block {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                        }                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        log_by_lua_block {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                balancer.log()                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                monitor.call()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                               
                                plugins.run()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                               
                        port_in_redirect off;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        set $balancer_ewma_score -1;                                                                                           
                        set $proxy_upstream_name "kube-system-kube-registry-proxy-80";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                        set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        set $pass_server_port    $server_port;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                               
                        set $best_http_host      $http_host;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                        set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                               
                        set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        client_max_body_size                    1024m;                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        # Custom headers to proxied server   
                  
                        proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                        proxy_send_timeout                      60s;                                                                           
                        proxy_read_timeout                      60s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        proxy_buffering                         off;                                                                           
                        proxy_buffer_size                       8k;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                        proxy_buffers                           4 8k;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                               
                        proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        proxy_request_buffering                 on;                                                                            
                        ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                }                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        ## end server <redactedDomain>
```

However, this didn't seem to help. I have tried setting `client-max-body-size` to 0 as well.

**My question is: how can I prevent a 413 HTTP status code that most likely comes from the ingress-nginx-controller?**

Comment: You may also need to configure php to accept large uploads, see [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fix-client-intended-to-send-too-large-body-xyz-bytes-in-nginx/). Add to `php.ini` the two lines `upload_max_filesize=1024M` and `post_max_size=1024M`.

Comment: I believe that that is only for when you run a php-fpm server behind it. I saw that the docker registry is using python and nginx is written in c, so I don't think that this applies here. Thanks for the try anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is found in [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/):

```
http {
    ...
    # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
    client_max_body_size 0;
    ...
}
```

So it seems that the solution is that the limit should be turned off.

Comment: I actually started with setting client_max_body_size 0, but after that didn't work, I tried setting it to 1024m, a size that would definitely be big enough for a couple of 30m files. So unfortunately this wasn't the solution for me.

Comment: You mean that this was the setup at the time that it still worked? What has changed since then (new version etc.) ?

Comment: I mean that neither 0 nor 1024m work. I have not been able to get it to work ever since I added ssl to the connection. Maybe that is relevant, but I don't see how it would give a 413 error, where it didn't before...

Comment: On the host, I'm only exposing the registry to the host machine (using lan IP). This connection uses ssl. The connection between the host nginx to the cluster nginx and onwards is still unsecured.

Comment: If I understand right: The setup is computer1 that passes a request to computer2. This stopped working when computer1 was configured with SSL while computer2 wasn't. Question: Which computer answers the request?

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps installing the certificate also in computer2 will help.

Comment: I have one computer (lets call it the host machine) that uses nginx to handle external connections and reroute it to a virtual machine that also runs on the host (set up with minikube using hyperv). On this virtual machine, I have a nginx ingress controller that routes requests to the specific services. External requests are secured with ssl. Requests between nginx outside and nginx inside the vm is insecure, just as requests between nginx inside the vm and the services that run on that vm. The vm never sees ssl secured data. This works flawlessly for all my other services.

Comment: This is a much more complex question than was originally posted. If this worked for other services, you should have the needed configuration files, unless the other ones don't use SSL.

Comment: The other services also use SSL. The difference with other services is that kube registry works with large docker images. Therefore the other services never ran into the issue of a 413 error.

Comment: The ssl thing might be a red herring, since there is no actual ssl traffic from the host nginx to the nginx ingress controller inside the vm. I just thought it was a good idea to mention this, to make the info more complete.

Comment: And normally you would think that your solution actually would resolve the issue. I also found this info. I wouldn't have asked the question here on superuser if that was the case. But hopefully others might benefit from your answer, as it indeed normally would fix the problem, so I upvoted you for that, even though it is not the solution.

Comment: In the end, I switched to HAProxy and never looked back, since that worked like a charm.